# How to create new storefront/website in hybris with hmc

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

Can anyone please provide some steps to create a new website using storefront extension.

---

default from hybris,

I have used modulegen to create new B2C modules with name : jewels,
so i have 7 extensions generated in custom as jewelscore, jewelsstorefront, ...

http://localhost:9001/jewelsstorefront/?site=apparel-uk  OR apparel-de
is working ok.

I want to create my own website here for development perspective and it should be like [http://localhost:9001/jewelsstorefront/ ]

Please suggest me some steps to create my own website.

Comment: Hybris not known to me, but maybe even with hybris, could there be some code snippets included in the question, to help others knowing to help you? We are all coders here ...

Answer (score 2):

Please follow Hybris Commerce Side trails (Optional Preparation Steps) to setup your website.

https://wiki.hybris.com/display/R5T/hybris+5+Developer+Training+Trails+5.7+-+Part+II+-+Commerce

If you want to proceed with HMC. You can follow this link

https://wiki.hybris.com/display/release5/cms2+Extension+Tutorial

Answer (score 0):

image:
[image]

```html
<img src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtlSn.png'/>
```

/>
Have you manage Frontend Template Name appropriately in your jewellery content catalog as above.